# Adding a Background URL to an Advanced Custom Field

Tags: html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to add a background url to a DIV alongside an advanced custom field.
http://placehold.it/1000x500
Like this : [Custom Fields for Div background images? (wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073104/custom-fields-for-div-background-images-wordpress)

In the Advanced Custom Field I have tried text, wysiwyg, link picker...

However, when the page is loaded the / seem to be stripped out and "" are also in there.

Any ideas on getting this working

Here is the code I have tried:

```
<div class="clearfix featuresStrip homeBBanner-edit homeBBanner         
    style="background-image:url('<a href="<?php the_field('background_url'); ?>. </a>');">
    style="background-image: url('<a href="<?php the_field('background_url'); ?>. </a>');">
    style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('background_url'); ?>');">
```

Comment: That “code you tried” makes no sense from start to finish. Apart from that you neglected to properly close attribute values several times – what makes you think outputting `<a href=…>. </a>` as the content of the `url` value for `background-image` would make _any_ sense? This sounds like you need to go read up on some CSS basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should test to set `No formatting` for this field as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

One other thing that might be a problem is that you don't close the first attribute (class) in your element:

```
                                                               |
                                                               v
<div class="clearfix featuresStrip homeBBanner-edit homeBBanner style="
```

In fact, your entire markup looks suspicious, what are the anchor tag doing here `background-image:url('<a href="<?php the_field('background_url'); ?>. </a>');`?

Try changing your code to something along these lines:

```
<div class="clearfix featuresStrip homeBBanner-edit homeBBanner" style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('background_url'); ?>');">
...
</div>
```

The above assumes that the `background_url` field is plain text.

Comment: Silly error on my part, didn't close off the class. That fixed it.